# Other items in action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want to put a check mark on my action bar instead of the 3 dots menu. The activity will then be finished after the check is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new folder under `res` folder named `menu`. Right click it and add a new menu resource, name it something like mymenu.xml. Add this code:

```
<item
    android:title="check"
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

You can change the icon to any other. Handle it in `onOptionsItemSelected` (like in above reply).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding your own menu in your activity/fragment.

and after adding all that use something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.tick:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```